# Objects not falling with Parent

Tags: parent, soft-body

I'm trying to make an object bounce. There are many parts that are parented to the large sphere that I applied soft body physics to.

When I run the simulation, the children do not fall with the parent, the children should take on the attributes of the parent and follow the parent when it moves.

Answer (score 1):

The children won't follow a parent that has soft body, but you can select the children, shift select the parent, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices of the parent mesh and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent* and they will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to create a vertex group in the object to be followed, add copy location constraint in object that should follow and select the vertex group:

[image]